# vim-plug not recognizing plugins?

Tags: neovim

I put [this](https://nippycodes.com/coding/jdhs-neovim-vimrc/) in my init.vim file, yet when I run :PlugInstall, vim-plug does not show any of those plugins. Am I doing something wrong, or is vim-plug not working? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell vim-plug where to installed the plugins:

Change

```
call plug#begin()
```

to

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
```